# C# calling on a textbox from a different form

Tags: c#

I am trying to access the textbox of form1 (Econtact) from form2. I made the textbox public but it didn't help.

This is the code in form2

```
    TextBox Form2txtboxFirstName = Econtact.txtboxFirstName;
```

the following code is giving me the error **An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Econtact.txtboxFirstName'**

Comment: What part of the error message do you need help with? You need a reference to the class in order to access an instance member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Econtact form is child of Form2, then pass reference of Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private EContact _eContact;

    public Form2(EContact eContact)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _eContact = eContact;
        MsgBox.Show(_eContact.txtboxFirstName.Text);
    }       
}
```

inside EContact form however, you will have to pass the reference while calling the form2

```
var form2 = New Form2(this);
form2.Show();
```

Comment: i tried it, your code hepled me access the other form's text box so thank you. but the issue is that at the line of "MsgBox.Show(_eContact.txtboxFirstName);" it is giving me this error "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

Comment: sorry, didn't notice that... updated MsgBox line of code should help :)

Comment: it is still giving me the same error sadly :/ not sure why